Can you use arithmetic operators to flip between -1, 0, and 1?
What's a non-array, non modulo, arithmatic-based way to rotate between {-1, 0, 1}? Or {0, 1, 2}? Basically this question, but ternary instead binary.
I like the other question's answer (x = 1 - x), especially in that it can work for to any two numbers without using a modulo operator; that's boring (if you need a better reason for not using modulo operator, consider its expense with n-bit numbers, compared to add, subtract, and multiply). I just wonder what a simple ternary version of the provided binary solution might look like.
Edit: If flipping/rotating between 0 and 1 is binary, then flipping/rotating between three numbers would be ternary.
Thoughts?

You need to provide a much clearer specification of the problem.  What "arithmetic" operators ARE permitted?   What does "non-modulo" mean?  What are the constraints on the triple?

Bear in mind that "arithmetic operators" depends on the (programming) language you are using, and you haven't specified that.  (If you say "mathematical" arithmetic operators, then there is no universal set of "mathematical" arithmetical operators.  New mathematical operators can be defined at will.)

And even "flip between" needs to be defined.

What is a ternary flip?

Does that a Wikipedia article actually talk about the modulo operator?

Is “its expense with n-bit numbers” the reason you ruled out modulo, or is it an arbitrary justification after the fact? Because these aren’t n-bit numbers – they’re 2-bit numbers. And if you want optimal performance in some context, you should say so, because lots of mod-avoiding alternatives could be slower than mod. (For example, clang can optimize it to a simple conditional move. And in general, a constant modulus can be optimized to a multiplication and some shifts, which makes manual solutions that do a multiplication and shifts a waste of time.)

@Ry, It's an arbitrary justification, plain and simple. Says so in the post. The whole post is purely a theortetical exploration, where % operator is an obvious anwer that won't teach much. But if exploration alone doesn't motivate you, then read on for a valid alt. reason: The above number set is comprised of 1- and 2-bit numbers (both ∈ n, i.e. all real integers). The post says that the previous solution can expand to any number, so imagine a solution that could do the same, and would thus be useful for n-bit numbers given %(n) ∈  O(+(n)), O(-(n)), and at best Θ(*(n)).

What does that notation mean?

@DrewGalbraith your latest edit about “flipping/rotating” still doesn’t make sense. Could you provide a specification of your expected output?

Additionally, the expense of modulo can be mitigated by considering that the output of many operations on mod-n numbers is bounded. For example, “x+1” will only ever be in the range [1,n] and so it can be efficiently reduced back to [0,n-1] by a conditional check. Similarly, “x+y” must be in [0, 2n) which again can be efficiently reduced by a conditional and subtraction. Modulo isn’t necessary in many cases.

You haven’t defined the operation, but here’s a way to implement any unary operation on a ternary input (0, 1, 2) using only bitwise operations and a constant integer which defines the operation:
def unary_op(op, x):
    return (op >> (x << 1)) & 3

For example, to increment x (0,1,2 becomes 1,2,0), use unary_op(9, x). To invert x (0,1,2 becomes 2,1,0), use unary_op(6, x), and so on. In general, to implement a function which turns 0,1,2 into x,y,z, set op to 16z + 4y + x.
This is similar to an array-driven approach in principle but encodes the table much more compactly.

x = (1 << x) & 3 works for 0->1->2->0.
